# How to debug program compilation when Perl module fails

Tags: perl, compilation, raspbian

I'm trying to compile [Slic3r 1.2.9 (Git 65a23b)](https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/tree/1.2.9) on Raspbian, and running `sudo perl Build.PL --verbose` fails while  building the Perl module Time-HiRes-1.9754:

```
...
--> Working on Time::HiRes
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JH/JHI/Time-HiRes-1.9754.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Time-HiRes-1.9754 ... FAIL
! Timed out (> 60s). Use --verbose to retry.
! Configure failed for Time-HiRes-1.9754. See /root/.cpanm/work/1520227993.988/build.log for details.
```

The log file shows a little more information, but I've never worked with Perl and I don't know where to start debugging:

```
$ tail /root/.cpanm/work/1520234788.2186/build.log
Looking for clock_getres()... found.
Looking for clock_nanosleep()... found.
Looking for clock()... found.
Looking for working futimens()... found.
Looking for working utimensat()... found.
You seem to have subsecond timestamp setting.
Looking for stat() subsecond timestamps...
Trying struct stat st_atimespec.tv_nsec...-> FAIL Timed out (> 60s). Use --verbose to retry.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Time-HiRes-1.9754. See /root/.cpanm/work/1520234788.2186/build.log for details.
```

I've posted an [issue with Slic3r](https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/issues/4336) on GitHub, but I haven't had any suggestions yet - presumably it's not actually a problem with Slic3r itself.

What should I do next to work out what's going wrong?

Comment: Look inside the Build script and see if there is a minimum version of Time::HiRes you could install, then try to install it with cpan / cpanm.

Comment: https://www.cpantesters.org/distro/T/Time-HiRes.html seems to pass on all Debian flavors (I don't know about Raspian), and version 1.9757 seems to be the latest, you are trying 1.9754

Comment: The build script doesn't specify a minimum version, so I ran `sudo cpanm Time::HiRes` on its own, but it failed in the same way, using version 1.9757. Weirdly, using `--verbose` with `cpanm` allowed it to compile successfully. I'll try the build script again later and see how it goes.

Comment: You should try and look at the whole log. This looks like part of a configuration script for that module itself or some upstream dependency. If it fails, might be because some upstream, non-Perl library is not installed. That is part of the configuration of the module, which tries to compile a small program https://metacpan.org/source/JHI/Time-HiRes-1.9757/Makefile.PL (check out line 744). Extract that program from there to see what's going on. It might have to do with the fact that it's a Raspi, but then it's a timeout... Difficult to say.